# Fragments above ViewPager not scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, scroll, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and below that I have a `LinearLayout` with 2 `fragments` and a `ViewPager`. However, when I am scrolling, both `fragments` stay sticky and only the `viewpager` containing a `RecyclerView` is scrolling properly. How can I make both `fragments` `scrollable` as well?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="90dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hero"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ButtonBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center|start"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SignUpButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_white_inverted_selector"
                android:textColor="@drawable/rounded_border_white_text_inverted_selector"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_white_selector"
                android:textColor="@drawable/rounded_border_white_text_selector"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_half"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSponsored"
        android:name="SponsoredFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sponsored" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentAnnouncement"
        android:name="AnnouncementFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_announcement" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainactivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyPagerAdapter TabAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {

                case 0:
                    return SHGCreationFragmentFirst.newInstance("SHGCreationFragmentFirst, Instance 1");
                case 1:
                    return MemberListFragment.newInstance("MemberListFragment, Instance 2");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

    }
}
```

FragmentFirst

```
public class FragmentFirst extends Fragment {



       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

       return v;
   }

    public static FragmentFirst newInstance(String text) {

        FragmentFirst f = new FragmentFirst();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }


}
```

FragmentSecond

```
public class FragmentSecond extends Fragment {



           @Override
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

           return v;
       }

        public static FragmentSecond newInstance(String text) {

            FragmentSecond f = new FragmentSecond();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("msg", text);

            f.setArguments(b);

            return f;
        }


    }
```

fragment_first.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">


        </LinearLayout>
```

fragment_Second.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fcfcfc"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't address the problem. By scrollable I mean up and down, not swiping left and right. When I scroll the RecyclerView contained on the ViewPager, the two fragments on top of the ViewPager are stickied to the top. What I want is to make them scrollable as well.